# Remove style property using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, attr, removeclass

I have this style property in my css file:

```
.table tbody tr:hover th,
.table tbody tr:hover td { background: #d1e5ef; }
```

I would like to remove this via jquery, how would I go about doing this? I tried removeClass and attr but doesnt work.

Comment: Do you want to remove the complete style definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some more css to make this work:

```
.table tbody tr:hover th,
.table tbody tr:hover td { background: #d1e5ef; }

.table tbody tr.no-hover:hover th,
.table tbody tr.no-hover:hover td { background: inherit; }
```

You would add the class `.no-hover` using `$(selector).addClass('no-hover')`. This will style them differently than the other `:hover` definitions you have. You may have to use an explicit color to make this work.

Comment: Thanks for the code, basically I didnt want the hover property at all when a person is viewing the page on an ipad. This is because on an ipad the hover affects the scrolling, when I remove this property the scrolling on the ipad works just fine. But I dont want to remove it for normal desktop/laptop systems.

Answer (score 1):

You have to work around that, because jQuery doesn't support pseudo-classes. For more information, see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/deactivating-the-hover-state-of-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

you define the style on object not by using class so obviously you can't remove them.

their is some option you can use

add a class to td like

1    `.class1{ background: transparent;}`

when you add this class through jQuery that is will work

2  change the color through jQuery

```
$('table tr td').css('background-color','transparent')
```

try this option and i thing it will work.

Answer (score -1):

add class to `td` and style it, not the tag itself and then use `removeClass()` or add class in `hover()`